# 2checkout standard checkout automatic redirect

Tags: payment-gateway, 2checkout

I have implemented 2checkout standard checkout on my site. I handle the response returned after payment but only after a customer clicks on **Finalize Order**. Does 2checkout allow automatic redirects and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use header redirect return option. Get the response via $_GET

http://help.2checkout.com/articles/FAQ/How-Does-The-Return-Process-Work?_ga=2.73341018.879443581.1495957169-624661817.1495955299